# Summing up a dynamic range of multiple columns and rows

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have a peculiar issue, i.e., not only the values in rows and columns changes continuously, occasionally the number of rows too varies; say anywhere between 30 to 70 rows.  I have tried a code (I am new to excel vba...) as below in which I was able to copy the selected code to another sheet.  This is because, as the row changes, the sum of each column is incorrect and in order to fix this, I am trying to copy the data from the source sheet to another sheet. Any help in fixing the code is great!.. Thank You!!

Data Structure As Below:

```
A   B   C
229 498 134
119 111 314
298 265 698
298 264 124
427 373 174
102 532 245
```

The Excel VBA Code

```
Sub dynamicRange()

Dim startCell As Range, lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long, Ws As Worksheet

Set Ws = Sheets("N_TS")
Set startCell = Range("A3")

lastRow = Ws.cells(Ws.Rows.Count, startCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
lastCol = Ws.cells(startCell.Row, Ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Ws.Range(startCell, Ws.cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Select
Selection.Select
Selection.Copy Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1")

End Sub
```

Note - It is above End Sub, that I don't know how to write the code to sum up all the columns simultaneously as a Range...

Comment: So, you want to compute the *sum* of all the entries in the range?

Comment: To be more clearer, I expect the SUM of each column to be seen in the same column.  As I have explained, the Row changes (sometimes to be 4 or even 10 less and then within a minute or so, would be added.  It is based on the log inputs of the users. Hope I have explained vividly.... Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

> don't know how to write the code to sum up all the columns simultaneously as a Range

Drop the last three lines and put this instead:

```
With Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1").Resize(lastCol)
  .Formula = "=SUM('N_TS'!A3:A" & lastRow & ")"
  .Value = .Value
End With
```

Comment: Hi, the code only calculates the SUM of (? unable to understand how the following came......A1-1244, A2-1125, A3-827 as a single column. Actually, since the N_TS sheet's row dynamically varies as data flows through, I thought to copy the data till last row to a new sheet "3" and then SUM up all the columns in sheet3. This formula doesn't serve my purpose...
.